# Getting data of another JFrame when JFrame is displayed

Tags: java, jframe, drawing

I've two classes which extends JFrame. firstly i'm taking input from One Jframe and displaying graph on another JFrame but in second JFrame it also shows content of first Jframe. Here is code

```
class upgma extends JFrame
{
static int width;
static int height;
JPanel c;
int titem;
volatile boolean called;
static String finalans;
upgma()
{
    c = new JPanel();
    called = false;
    JTextField items;
    JButton init;
    c.setLayout(null);
    items=new JTextField();
    JLabel ni = new JLabel("Number of items");
    ni.setBounds(width/2-95,height/2-50,100,20);

    items.setBounds(width/2-100,height/2-20,100,20);
    init = new JButton("Next");
    init.setBounds(width/2+15,height/2-20,80,20);
    init.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if(items.getText().isEmpty() || !items.getText().matches("[1-9]?[0-9]*"))
            {
                JLabel e=new JLabel("Please Enter VALID Data !! ");
                e.setBounds(width/2-85,height/2+20,200,20);
                c.add(e);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
            else
                enterData(items);
        }
    });
    c.add(ni);
    c.add(items);
    c.add(init);

    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(c);
    jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
    height = (int)screenSize.getHeight()-40;
    System.out.println(width+""+height);
    upgma u = new upgma();
    u.setSize(width,height);
    u.setVisible(true);
    u.setTitle("Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic Mean");

    while(!u.called);

    u.setVisible(false);
    u = null;
    drawing  d= new drawing(finalans);
    d.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
    ((JComponent) d.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
    d.setSize(width,height);
    d.setVisible(true);
    d.setTitle("Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic Mean demo");
    }

}
```

and another class is as follows:

```
class drawing extends JFrame
{
Container c1;
static int width;
static int height;
String data;

drawing(String temp)
{
    data = temp;
    c1=getContentPane();
    c1.setLayout(null);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
    height = (int)screenSize.getHeight()-40;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paint(g);
    Font font = g.getFont().deriveFont( 20.0f );
    g.setFont( font );
    if(data.isEmpty())
    {   
        JLabel er = new JLabel("Nothing to Show !!");
        er.setBounds(width/2-100,height/2,150,40);
        c1.add(er);
    }
    else
    {
        int length = data.length();         
        draw(g,data,width/2-length*7,40);
    }
}
}
```

and it shows me like this: Tree printed over here .i'm printing it in my drawing class.That textfields it is showing is of first class upgma which extends JFrame.[image]

I'm not getting where i'm doing wrong.. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're making it transparent.

```
((JComponent) d.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: But that is of another JFrame and two classes r different. Still it can create this problem ? And I wanted to draw on JFrame and I found this code so that I can draw on frame.

Comment: Basically, setting this method is the Java equivalent of saying "I want to draw this on a pane of glass rather than a piece of wood."  When you draw on said pane of glass, you will still be able to see what's behind it.

Comment: So if I remove this line then will I still be able to draw on frame using same code or do I need to change anything ?@Joe C

Comment: I don't see what else you'd need to change here.

Comment: OK. I'll check it and let u know.